# Not able to read SECRET_KEY_BASE from environment while using Capistrano and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, capistrano

When using Nginx, Passenger, Capistrano, and RVM together I am unable to get the `secrets.yml` to read the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` from `ENV`. Basically the same issue [this guy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/rails-4-1-4-production-environment-ubuntu-apache-passenger?comment=38356) has.

I get a 502 error and the log shows that passenger believes the SECRET_KEY_BASE is not set.

This value is set on boot in `/etc/environment`.

It appears that global env variables aren't shared with my RVM env. A quick solution would be to use any of [these methods](http://trevmex.com/post/58452818690/they-did-it-rvm-can-now-store-environment) but because of capistrano these would be overwritten on each new deployment.

I could solve THAT issue by using Capistrano to set the variable, but then I'd have to store it in the repo in order for multiple developers to be able to deploy and that defeats the purpose.

So the question is: How do I get the SECRET_KEY_BASE set as an environment variable RVM will recognize without haveing to store it in the repo or on any developer machine?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to setting env variables with your current setup:

- dotenv gem
- What Passenger suggests here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html
- Setting it on your server config file: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_env

I would go with the first approach